# How to validate EntityType in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I made form using form builder

```
$builder
        ->add('name', null, [
            'attr' => ['autofocus' => true],
            'label' => 'label.name',
        ])
        ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => City::class,
                // uses the City.name property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'choose.city'
        ])
        ->add('university', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => University::class,
                // uses the University.name property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'name',
        ])
        ->add('courses', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => Course::class,
                // uses the University.name property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
        ])
    ;
```

Now my form looks like this
[image]

I want for dropdown choices to be integers and not blank.

For single dropdowns all I need to add is: `@Assert\NotBlank(message="student.university_not_blank")`

1. How can I set that those values on single dropdown should be integers?
2. How can I validate multiple choice dropdown not to be blank and its values to be integers?